# JOIN shows data twice in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
SELECT *
FROM `all_salary_slip_details` `assd`
INNER JOIN `employee_master` `em` ON `assd`.`EMPLOYEE_ID` = `em`.`EMPLOYEE_ID`
INNER JOIN `employee_details` `ed` ON `assd`.`EMPLOYEE_ID` = `ed`.`EMPLOYEE_ID`
INNER JOIN `organizations` `o` ON `o`.`ORG_ID` = `assd`.`ORG_ID`
INNER JOIN `months` `mo` ON `mo`.`id` = `assd`.`PAY_MONTH`
```

This is my query to fetch data from db. I have only 4 rows but in my view I get 48 rows. I dont understand why this happens.

Comment: 4 rows in what? You are joining other tables, how many rows are in every table you have joined?

Comment: other tables so so much data within it. but `all_salary_slip_details` have only 4 rows. i am joining other tables because i want employee_name from employee_master , orgnisation_name from orgnizations table so on.

Comment: You know what this means, right? `SELECT *`

Comment: 48 rows or columns? How is the code being executed, DB interface direct or is PHP relevant here?

Comment: 48 rows. DB interface direct or is PHP relevant here? sorry i dont understand this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `GROUP BY` clause on a column, then your query will only return a single row for each unique entry in that column.

In your case I'm guessing it would make sense to use the employee name.

What result does this query output?

```
SELECT assd.PAY_YEAR, assd.PDF, em.EMPLOYEE_NAME, o.ORG_NAME, mo.month_name
FROM all_salary_slip_details assd
INNER JOIN employee_master em
ON assd.EMPLOYEE_ID = em.EMPLOYEE_ID
INNER JOIN organizations o
ON o.ORG_ID = assd.ORG_ID
INNER JOIN months mo
ON mo.id = assd.PAY_MONTH
GROUP BY em.EMPLOYEE_NAME
```

Comment: assd.PAY_YEAR,  assd.PDF, em.EMPLOYEE_NAME, o.ORG_NAME, mo.month_name i m using this but getting same result

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your original problem, Ive updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You will get 1 row returned in your query for each record in a joined table that matches the join condition.

So, if you have multiple records in any one of the employee_master, employee_details, organisations or months tables that match those in all_salary_slip_details you will get additional rows returned. Look at the rows returned, you will see differences in each and where they differ will tell you where the join condition for the table isn't specific enough to return a single row.